# sending jquery function through html input

Tags: jquery, html

Quick question:

How can I add the height and width from this function (`onResize`) to the canvas or hidden input. I don't want it to use the 198x55 where it says that I want it to use the `onResize` height and width.

Here is the function:

```
<script>
  (function(window) {
    var $canvas,
        onResize = function(event) {
          $canvas.attr({
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth
          });
        };

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $canvas = $('canvas');
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', onResize, false);
      window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
      onResize();

      $('form').signaturePad({
        drawBezierCurves: true,
        variableStrokeWidth:true,
        drawOnly: true,
        defaultAction: 'drawIt',
        validateFields: false,
        lineWidth: 0,
        output: null,
        sigNav: null,
        name: null,
        typed: null,
        clear: 'input[type=reset]',
        typeIt: null,
        drawIt: null,
        typeItDesc: null,
        drawItDesc: null
      });
    });
  }(this));
</script>
```

and here is the HTML part

```
<canvas class="pad" width="198" height="55"></canvas>
<input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
```

Basically I want it to know that the canvas is not 198x55 but it equals the same as the function `onResize` and I want it to save it for post through the hidden input

and then when it sends to the next page I also need this to equal it aswell..

```
'imageSize' => array(198, 55)
```

Comment: Should be able to use jQuery to grab the current values of height and width of the canvas element and use those values where needed.

Comment: Not what I mean. I want to send the height and width of the onResize function to the next page via the hidden output. I want those values too know that the hieght changed from 198x55 and they are now Onresize.

Comment: Can you just change the `value()` of the hidden `input` in the onResize function to the `height` and `width` you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be quite easy. You just set the value of your hidden input in your `onResize` function:

```
<script>
  (function(window) {
    var $canvas,
        $output,
        onResize = function(event) {
          $canvas.attr({
            height: window.innerHeight,
            width: window.innerWidth
          });
          $output.val(window.innerWidth + ',' + window.innerHeight);
        };

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $canvas = $('canvas');
      $output = $('input[name="output"]');
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', onResize, false);
      window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
      onResize();

      $('form').signaturePad({
        drawBezierCurves: true,
        variableStrokeWidth:true,
        drawOnly: true,
        defaultAction: 'drawIt',
        validateFields: false,
        lineWidth: 0,
        output: null,
        sigNav: null,
        name: null,
        typed: null,
        clear: 'input[type=reset]',
        typeIt: null,
        drawIt: null,
        typeItDesc: null,
        drawItDesc: null
      });
    });
  }(this));
</script>
```

And in php you do this to get an array of width, height:

```
'imageSize' => explode(',', $_POST['output'], 2)
```